# Reputation notification discrepancy?

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, reputation-history

Where is the `+16` coming from?  I assume the badge corresponds with the blue highlighted events, but that only adds up to 15.  If it went any further back it would be over 20.  I don't see any way to get 16.

[image]

Comment: Most probably a question you downvoted has been deleted and you got the 1 rep back.

Comment: See the duplicate; something got deleted.

Comment: @BDL Answer, not question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An answer you downvoted somewhere on the network has been deleted.

Since you lose 1 rep for downvoting an answer, you get it back if the answer gets deleted. However, this event won't show up in your achievement dropdown. This makes sense, since the post in question is, well, deleted. There isn't anything for them to link to, at least as far as most users are concerned.